# How to implement Facebook check-in-like view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to implement a view that behaves like the one in the Facebook app when you want to check in.

In it's initial state it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4WDh.png

The top most view is the map(in this case), below there is the search bar and a list of items.

When the user scrolls up, the view will look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGhPu.png

The bottom list view and the search bar will use less space and the map's height will increase and will center the content within the new frame. Upon stopping the scroll, the view will resume to it's initial state.

When scrolling down, the list view items will take up as much space as it can.

I have tried using ScrollTricks by Roman Nurik and Nick Butcher to implement this behavior, but did not succeed because in this project, the top view does not increase it's size once the user scrolls up.

Do you know of any third party libraries that implement this behavior or do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView

Answer (score 0):

this library might be the solution
https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView